# How to use to_char function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
delete from student where to_char (Student_id) like '432%';
```

Is `to_char` function here is true used? because my error displays is:

> FUNCTION to_char does not exist

Comment: I don't think you can compare to the result of a function like that, it would have to call that function on every field in the table

Comment: you dont, it doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1):

TO_CHAR is for Oracle, see: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/to_char_datetime

If you want to delete all student ids that look like "432" or "43234" or "432 ..." just use the wildcard like you've already posted it.

If you want to delete all entries greater or equal to 432:

```
delete from student where Student_id >= 432
```

Comment: Yes ,I want to delete all student ids that looks like 432 but it gives me an error in to_char function

Answer (score 0):

Use cast OR convert:

```
delete from student where convert(Student_id,char(50)) like '432%';
delete from student where cast(Student_id as char(50)) like '432%';
```